# align vertically checkbox in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, checkbox

I am developping an asp.net application and I would like to have a list of checkbox, like this :

checkbox1
checkbox2
...

Actually I am having this :

checkbox1 checkbox2 ...

This is my "page.aspx":

```
<asp:Panel ID="Panel1" runat="server">
</asp:Panel>
```

This is my "page.aspx.cs":

```
for(int i=0;i<5;i++)
            {
                CheckBox c = new CheckBox();
                c.Text = "c"+i;
                c.ID = "c"+i;
                Panel1.Controls.Add(c);                    
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could add a css rule where you set their `display` property to `block`. Through `display:block` they force a line break.

Answer (score 0):

you can use check box list for this and add check boxes at run time using your code

Checkboxlist.items.add(check box);

And set the Repeatdirection property to vertically of checkboxlist on aspx page